# Why wasn't Vincent more furtive in the bathroom?

Tags: pulp-fiction

In *Pulp Fiction* (1994), when Butch goes back to get his watch, he enters the apartment.  After perceiving that he is alone, he relaxes, starts moving normally, even makes a pop-tart.

Wouldn't all of this movement have caused enough noise for Vincent to hear?  When the door opens, Vincent has the look of a man unaware of his surroundings.  I would expect that not only he would have heard Butch, but try to be more discreet about getting out of the bathroom.

Comment: What bothered me for a while was, why did he leave his gun in kitchen. But then who's to blame, it's a fiction after all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoting directly from [fandom](https://pulpfiction.fandom.com/wiki/Vincent_Vega#The_gold_watch) as there is nothing much to explain here,

> While Marsellus and Vincent are staking out Butch's apartment, Marsellus leaves to get them some coffee and Vincent goes into the bathroom. Butch warily walks in to retrieve a forgotten watch and finds a Silenced MAC-11 on the kitchen counter. As he picks it up, Butch hears the toilet flush in the bathroom. Vincent walks out and freezes, recognizing Butch and staring into the barrel of his boss' gun. Seconds go by, a pair of Pop-Tarts jump out of the toaster and Butch shoots Vincent in the chest, killing him.

So the answer to your question is,

Vincent must have thought that his boss has returned that's why he was not so discreet while getting out of bathroom. And the gun was left by Marsellus because it was big enough and difficult to hide under coat if he were to go get a coffee.

Comment: Ah.  Then my recollection was off.  Butch did not make the pop-tart.  I thought I did remember him letting his guard down though.  I thought maybe he did make some noise.

Comment: @JasonPSallinger: Yes he did. But Vincent thought it was Marsellus who has returned.

Comment: It does speak to some lack of caution on Vince's part, but he probably strongly believed that Butch would not do anything so stupid as coming back to his apartment.

Comment: @ruffdove - You hit the nail on the head. Vincent was lacking situational discipline because (besides the fact that he habitually did drugs) he thought that only an idiot or a madman would return to his apartment after screwing over Wallis. Plus, Vincent had a gun. He was only backup for Wallis who had more guns. What could go wrong?

Comment: One thing to notice is that whenever Vincent returned from bathroom/toilet/washroom something bad happened.